# How does Python resolve decorator names

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I have the following code:

```
import threading
from functools import wraps
class Synchronized(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def synchronized(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with self.lock:
                print "here"
                return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    @synchronized
    def go(self):
        print 1

class B(Synchronized):
    @synchronized
    def foo(self):
        return 1
```

This code fails on import complaining:

```
  File "a.py", line XXX, in B
    @synchronized
NameError: name 'synchronized' is not defined
```

However if I comment out B and just use `Syncrhonized().go()` it works great.

***Question:*** How does python know what is `@synchronized` in base class but fails to resolve it in its derivatives?

Comment: Why do you want synchronized to be a method, not a function?

Comment: Because I want to keep it inside the class for better code organization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`synchronized` is defined as a function in the class body of `Synchronized` *only*.

A class body is executed like a function to define the class; the resulting local namespace is used to form the class attributes. This is why `synchronized` is still a local name within `Synchronized` when used as a decorator on `go`. You could compare that with defining the decorator inside a function, then trying to apply it *outside* of that function; it won't work, because the decorator is a local variable.

You could use `@Syncronized.synchronized.im_func` in class `B` (`.im_func` to unwrap the function from the method wrapper):

```
class B(Synchronized):
    @Synchronized.synchronized.im_func
    def foo(self):
        return 1
```

Better still, do not defined the decorator inside a class *at all* but instead defined it *outside* of `Synchronized`. It is not a method, after all:

```
def synchronized(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with self.lock:
            print "here"
            return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class Synchronized(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    @synchronized
    def go(self):
        print 1

class B(Synchronized):
    @synchronized
    def foo(self):
        return 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Yeah, I know I can define decorator outside the class, but then you need to import two things if you use it as a helper mode. Alternatively I can decorate <code>synchronized</code> with @staticmethod and use it only in derived classes.

Comment: You can use it in the base too: `@synchronize.__func__`.